# How to extract all rows between start signal and end signal?

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering

I have the following `df` and I would like to extract all rows based on the following start and end signals.

Start signal : When status changes from 1 to 0 
End signal   : When status changes from 0 to -1.

```
df <- data.frame(time = rep(1:14), status = c(0,1,1,0,0,0,-1,0,1,0,0,0,-1,0))

   time status
1     1      0
2     2      1
3     3      1
4     4      0
5     5      0
6     6      0
7     7     -1
8     8      0
9     9      1
10   10      0
11   11      0
12   12      0
13   13     -1
14   14      0
```

Desire:

```
   time status    
4     4      0
5     5      0
6     6      0
10   10      0
11   11      0
12   12      0
```

Comment: Start signal is defined when status changes from 1 to 0  and end signal is as from 0 to -1. So, in the example, I'd like to get all rows from 4 to 6 and 10 to 12 .

Answer (score 6):

Here's a possible solution using the `data.table` package. I'm basically first grouping by `status == 1` appearances and then checking per group if there was also a `status == -1`, if so, I'm sub-setting the group from the second incident until the `-1` incident minus 1

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, indx := cumsum(status == 1)]
df[, if(any(status == -1)) .SD[2:(which(status == -1) - 1)], by = indx]
#    indx time status
# 1:    2    4      0
# 2:    2    5      0
# 3:    2    6      0
# 4:    3   10      0
# 5:    3   11      0
# 6:    3   12      0
```

Answer (score 2):

We count start and end markers, then use those values and the cumulative-sum of (start - end) to filter rows. The `(cumsum(start)-cumsum(end)>1)` is a slight fiddle to avoid the cumulative counts being upset by row 2 which starts but doesn't end; otherwise row 14 would unwantedly get included.

```
require(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(start=(status==1), end=(status==-1)) %>%
       filter(!start & !end & (cumsum(start)-cumsum(end)>1) ) %>%
       select(-start, -end)

#   time status
# 1    4      0
# 2    5      0
# 3    6      0
# 4   10      0
# 5   11      0
# 6   12      0
```

Comment: @David Arenburg: that has everything to do with the question stated **"extract all rows when status = 1 as start signal and status = -1 as end signal"**. The OP then completely changes the question in a comment added under the question. Less snark, please.

Comment: OP wants to extract all rows between a sequence of 1 and -1, looks very clear to me.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: **"I would like to extract all rows when status = 1 as start signal and status = -1 as end signal"** literally asks for all rows with status == +1 or -1. Clearly that's not what they meant. As I already posted above I am revising my code based on OP's restated question.

Comment: This looks better now (+1)

Answer (score 1):

A little ugly, but you can always just loop over the values and keep a flag for determining whether the element should be kept or not.

```
keepers <- rep(FALSE, nrow(df))
flag <- FALSE
for(i in 1:(nrow(df)-1)) {
    if(df$status[i] == 1 && df$status[i+1] == 0) { 
        flag <- TRUE
        next  # keep signal index false
    }
    if(df$status[i] == -1 && df$status[i+1] == 0) {
        flag <- FALSE
        next  # keep signal index false
    }
    keepers[i] <- flag
}
keepers[nrow(df)] <- flag  # Set the last element to final flag value
newdf <- df[keepers, ]  # subset based on the T/F values determined
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have some more data (or can you gen some more data you know the outcome of) to see if this/these generalize?

Two similar approaches:

```
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame(time = rep(1:14), status = c(0,1,1,0,0,0,-1,0,1,0,0,0,-1,0))

dfr <- rle(df$status)

# first approach 

find_seq_str <- function() {
  str_locate_all(paste(gsub("-1", "x", dfr$values), collapse=""), "10")[[1]][,2]
}

df[as.vector(sapply(find_seq_str(), 
  function(n) {
    i <- sum(dfr$lengths[1:(n-1)])
    tail(i:(i+dfr$lengths[n]), -1)
  })),]


# second approach

find_seq_ts <- function() {
  which(apply(embed(dfr$values, 2), 1, function(x) all(x == c(0, 1))))
}

df[as.vector(sapply(find_seq_ts(), 
  function(n) {
    i <- sum(dfr$lengths[1:(n)])+1
    head(i:(i+dfr$lengths[n+1]), -1)
  })),]
```

Both approaches need a run length encoding of the `status` vector.

The first does a single character replacement for `-1` so we can make an unambiguous, contiguous string to then use `str_locate` to find the pairs that tell us when the target sequence starts then rebuilds the ranges of zeroes from the rle lengths.

If it needs to be base R I can try to whip up something with `regexpr`.

The second builds a paired matrix and compares for the same target sequence.

Caveats:

- I did no benchmarking
- Both create potentially big things if `status` is big.
- I'm not completely positive it generalizes (hence my initial q).
- David's is far more readable, maintainable & transferrable code but you get to deal with all the "goodness" that comes with using `data.table` ;-)

I wrapped the approaches in functions as they could potentially then be parameterized, but you could just as easily just assign the value to a variable or shove it into the `sapply` (ugh, tho).